# how does jQuery fade elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to select the `<img>` tags that are already faded with jQuery `fadeOut()` .
my idea is to select them with css attribute selector like this: `img[attr="smth"]` .
but i don't know what is the jQuery's algorithm to fade elements out and i don't know it turns which attribute's value to what in order to fade elements.
I have tried:

```
Console.log($("img").attr("opacity"));
Console.log($("img").attr("display"));
Console.log($("img").attr("visibility"));
```

But for all of them console says, undefined.
Does anyone know what attribute i should use?
Does anyone know any other way to do this without using css attribute selector?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the selector you're using. `attr()` is not a selector - it is something entirely different.

Comment: How do you select those images to apply fadeOut()? Use the same method. Or add a specific class or id while you fadeOut

Comment: Do you want to target all images that are hidden or just one's specifically hidden with `.fadeOut()`? Can you simply do `$('img:hidden')`? In addition, these values are not attributes. They're part of CSS which is the `style` attribute. Use `.css('opacity');`, `.css('display');` or `.css('visibility');` respectively.

Comment: They are not displayed after `fadeOut()` - what do you want to do with them?

Comment: @War10ck i think not!i didn't try, but as console reads visibility as undefined and hidden is a given value to visibility attribute, so that mustn't work.but i will try and tell if it worked:)

Comment: @aran The `:hidden` selector is not the same as `visibility: hidden;`. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) for reference...

Comment: @War10ck: yeah you are right:)i used .css and discovered that their display becomes none:) thank you so much! Now i found my answer but i will also try if :hidden works too:)

Comment: @LelioFaieta i select them one by one in a loop and then i want to access them all together:)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney i want to fade them in:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeIn():

```
display:none;
```

opacity going from 0 to 1 in defined timeframe

```
display: block or inline etc..
```

opacity is happening only for a fragment of second (by default).
You can check how is it working by inspecting element in your browser ;)

Comment: yeah thats it:)thank you! My mistake was using .attr instead of .css:)thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to add a class just when fading the element. Something like this:

```
// ... is your selector
$(...).fadeOut().addClass('img-faded');
```

After that you'll be able to fetch all *faded* images with:

```
var fadedImgs = $('img.img-faded');
```

Comment: Thanks for your creative suggestion, but in my case, it doesn't work, since my imgs already have classes and i need those classes:)

Comment: @aran you can add multiple classes to your elements.. i like this solution :)

Comment: @aran [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) doesn't remove previous classes. It only adds the new one specified by the parameter...

Comment: This is a clever example of finding only the images hidden by `.fadeOut()` as oppose to all hidden images. +1

Comment: @aran You can add zillion classes to your elements, DOM wont mind.

Comment: @War10ck: actually, i think: this still doesn't work for me since i have my images in loop and at each moment i want the images that are in the faded state and reveal them and so as time passes each image is faded out once but i only need the ones that are not yet revealed:) so, i will work with display:none finally:)

Comment: @aran use a class for the reavealed ones, and another class for the ones to be revealed, and a 3rd class for the ones that are shown. Don't be afraid of using classes.

Comment: @josegomezr but the thing is after a few minutes all of the images are faded in and out a few times so each image will have all the classes!

Comment: @aran no, each time an image is shown, you remove '.toBeRevealed'.. you can also load your images into array and rotate indexes, you will always know which image is being shown

Comment: @aran `.addClass()` has a counterpart `.removeClass()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrFadedElements = [];

// update YOUR-SELECTOR
$(".YOUR-SELECTOR").fadeOut(function() {
 arrFadedElements.push($(this));
});

console.log(arrFadedElements)
```